# Finding the Stats.max for each hierarchical index in Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

If I have a dataset that contains [City, Dealership, Total Cars Sold]. How would I get the top dealer in each city and the number of cars they sold?

The results should look like

```
City1 Dealership A 2000
City2 Dealership X 1000
etc.
```

I'm sure it's possible, but I'm not having any luck and it might because i'm approaching the problem the wrong way.

Currently i'm grouping by Dealership and City which creates a `Frame<(string*string*int), int>` and that gets me

```
City1 Dealership A 1 -> 2000
City1 Dealership B 2 -> 1000
City2 Dealership X 3 -> 1000
City2 Dealership Y 4 -> 500
etc.
```

But trying to then get the dealership that does the most deals is where i'm stumped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted Tomas's answer and output the type as `Series<string, (string * int)>`

```ml
let data = series [
  ("City1", "Dealership A") => 2000
  ("City1", "Dealership B") => 1000
  ("City2", "Dealership X") => 1000
  ("City2", "Dealership Y") => 500 ]

data
|> Series.groupBy (fun k _ -> fst k)
|> Series.mapValues (fun sr ->
  let sorted = sr |> Series.sortBy(fun x -> -x)
  let key = sorted |> Series.firstKey |> snd
  let value = sorted |> Series.firstValue
  key, value )
```

The output looks like

```
City1 -> (Dealership A, 2000) 
City2 -> (Dealership X, 1000)
```

**EDITED**

I assume you have a csv file like this

```
City,Dealership,TotalCarsSold
City1,Dealership A,2000
City1,Dealership B,1000
City2,Dealership X,1000
City2,Dealership Y,500
```

This is how I'll do it. Read it as `Frame` and get the column as `Series` and apply the same code above to get result.

```ml
let df = 
  Frame.ReadCsv("C:/Temp/dealership.csv")
  |> Frame.indexRowsUsing(fun r -> r.GetAs<string>("City"), r.GetAs<string>("Dealership"))
df?TotalCarsSold
|> Series.groupBy (fun k _ -> fst k)
|> Series.mapValues (fun sr ->
  let sorted = sr |> Series.sortBy(fun x -> -x)
  let key = sorted |> Series.firstKey |> snd
  let value = sorted |> Series.firstValue
  key, value )
```

Comment: zyzhu - I accepted the answer however you've changed the question slightly by using a `Series<(string * string), int>` instead of a `Frame<(string*string*int), int>`. Would you mind updating the answer or showing how to accomplish the same thing with a Frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `Series.applyLevel` function. It takes a series together with a key selector and then it applies a given aggregation to all rows that have the given key. In your case, the key selector just needs to project the dealership from the composed key of the series. Given your sample data:

```
let data = series [
  ("City1", "Dealership A") => 2000
  ("City1", "Dealership B") => 1000
  ("City2", "Dealership X") => 1000
  ("City2", "Dealership Y") => 500 ]
```

You can get the result by using:

```
data 
|> Series.applyLevel (fun (c, d) -> d) Stats.max
```

Note that `Stats.max` returns `option` (which is `None` for empty series). You can get a series with just numbers using:

```
data 
|> Series.applyLevel (fun (c, d) -> d) (Stats.max >> Option.get)
```

Comment: BTW, `Stats.max` and `Stats.min` no longer return `option` since https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle/pull/422

Comment: Thanks Tomas but when I run the code provided I get `Series<string,float>` which doesn't output the result i'm looking for. I'm trying to get the Dealership with the most sales in each city. Please see the result format i'm looking for in the question.